# How to test functions that return functions in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I want to test the following function within my node application.

```
var find_Primes = function(maximum_Number) {

    var index_Array = [], upper_Limit = Math.sqrt(maximum_Number), return_Array = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < maximum_Number; i++) {
        index_Array.push(true);
    }

    for (var i = 2; i <= upper_Limit; i++) {
        if (index_Array[i]) {
            for (var x = i * i; x <= maximum_Number; x += i) {
                index_Array[x] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 2; i < maximum_Number; i++) {
        if(index_Array[i]) {
            return_Array.push(i);
        }
    }
    return update_Primes(return_Array)
};
```

When my program starts I run find_Primes(max_Num) with the max number being a number passed as a command line argument.

**Issue:** I can test functions that return values pretty simply with mocha/chai, but I can't figure out how to test functions that return calls to other functions.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IIUC, you need to stub out the `update_Primes` function.

Comment: Not exactly sure what that means.  The update_Primes function updates records in a database and then returns a call to another function.

Comment: Is the problem that `update_Primes()` returns a function itself? Or that you don't want the test code to actually execute the code in `update_Primes()`? Because it seems to me like the test is pretty simple: Provide known inputs  to `find_Primes()` and check that you get the expected output. If you don't want to run the code in `update_Primes()` then you need to use a spy or a test double (such as a stub) for `update_Primes()`. But it's not clear to me that you need to do that here.

Comment: @user2263572, the code you posted does not return a function, nor does it return a call to another function. It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve or what your question is.

Comment: To clarify in more detail.  find_Primes returns a call to Update_Primes.  update_Primes return a call to another function.  And that function then returns a call to a final function.  I just want to test that the find_Primes function is finding the correct prime_Numbers and passing them along.